# Neo4j Stop Graph Traversal when a particular node in a set is reached

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to find the shortest path from a set of source nodes to a set of target nodes in a dense graph. an example of connections is

(Node1)-[:ConnectsTo]->(Node2)-[...]->(NodeN)->(NodeM)

The challenge I have is that NodeN might be connected to NodeM wherein both nodes are in my list of targets. I would like to stop traversing the path when any node in my list of targets is reached.

> ```
> Match (t:TestNode),(m:Node) where t.NODE_ID=m.NODE_ID    
> with m   
> MATCH path=shortestPath((m:Node)-[r:ConnectsTo*0..5]->(n:Node) )   
> where n.NODE_ID in    
> ['123','283','21232','244464','35102','38591','53011']    
> RETURN last(nodes(path)),collect(extract(e IN nodes(path)| e.name))
> ```

An example of the output is:

> ```
>      [[DF2396, GMPP, DelHub], [DF2396, GMPP]]
> ```

where both GMPP and DelHub are Targets, and GMPP has a connection to DelHub, so I'd like to stop and return only the second path upto GMPP.

Please let me know if you'd like more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have the answer worked out. I added a 'not any' for the path that checked nodes and excluded paths where a node in the target set was not the last node in the path. I also improved the formatting of the return set with an unwind on the collection of paths.

> ```
> Match (t:TestNode),(m:Node) where t.NODE_ID=m.NODE_ID    
> with m   
> MATCH path=shortestPath((m:Node)-[r:ConnectsTo*0..5]->(n:Node) )   
> where n.NODE_ID in    
> ['123','283','21232','244464','35102','38591','53011']    
> and not any(x in nodes(path) where x.NODE_ID in ['123','283','21232','244464','35102','38591','53011']  
> and x<>last(nodes(path)))
> with collect(extract(e IN nodes(path)| e.name)) as paths
> unwind (paths) as sequences
> ```

Comment: Pretty good, though one improvement you could make is to ensure in your `not any()` that you take the slice of the collection that omits the last node: `and not any(x in nodes(path)[..-1] where ...` That will let you remove the explicit predicate that x shouldn't be the last node in the path. Also, you can replace `not any()` with `none()`.

Comment: Thanks. I'll tweak that line. How does one retrieve the last but one node in each path and put them into a different collection?

Comment: That would be taking a slice from a collection. `nodes(path)[..-1]` gives you a collection of all nodes on the path except the last node (-1 place from the end). If you need all nodes except the first, then `tail(nodes(path))` should work.